# Target Audiences for a wiki page does not have any effect

Tags: 2013, development, audience-targeting, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection , I have defined that only users inside a SP group named "owners" are the Target Audiences for a wiki page as follow:-

[image]

but currently all users inside the visitors and contributors groups are able to view & edit this wiki page .. so can anyone adivce on this please ? i though defining "Owners" as the Target Audiences for a wiki page, will prevent users that are not defined inside the "Owners" group from seeing this wiki page ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audience is not equal to Security!

Audience on pages is mainly for showing / hiding the page from for example the current navigation, users will still be able to find and edit the page through links and site content for example